# Python django - ImportError: cannot import name comma_separated_int_list_re

Tags: python, django

When I run `python manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

```
from django.core.validators import (slug_re, comma_separated_int_list_re,
ImportError: cannot import name comma_separated_int_list_re`
```

Somebody help me!!! Thanks.

Comment: If you have an error, please post the version of Django that you are using, and the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `comma_separated_int_list_re` has been removed in Django 1.9 (see [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/3e64f3d0fc285080b42b78b67565b6ed939f9a24)), when the `int_list_validator` was added.

You can remove the import from your code, and define it yourself.

```
comma_separated_int_list_re = re.compile('^[\d,]+$')
```

Or you can extract the regex from `validate_comma_separated_integer_list`:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_comma_separated_integer_list
comma_separated_int_list_re = validate_comma_separated_integer_list.regex
```